Are we able to update JUnit Test Result into Build Pipeline through Azure Devops API?
I'm trying to upload some automation test result into Build Pipeline (In the Test and Coverage tab)
Upload target:

The test result is in JUnit format and is produced after the Release Pipeline done running and I can view it in the Release tab. To make it show up like that I used the Publish Test Result tasks
Want to view like this:

But now is there anyway for me to reuse those files and update to the Test and Coverage tab
One solution I see possible is that add a Power Shell task at the end of the Release Pipeline and use some kind of Azure Devops API to automatically update the Build Pipeline using JUnit files. But until now I haven't found any reference. If you guys know someone have done the similar thing like this I would be appreciated

It seems that you cannot link the test to the build from a release using the Azure DevOps Services REST API.
If you need the test results in the build, you should run the test during the build process.
You can also request a feature for Azure DevOps here to improve this functionality. Engineers typically prioritize features that are urgent or have more votes.
